# Send Email through Cayenne serial connection

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I have an Arduino Uno connected to Cayenne through the serial connection, currently i am reading the data from a sensor of temperature and humidity DHT12 and showing it in the Dashboard of Cayenne correctly.

I need to know if i can send emails from the Arduino using the connection that cayenne let me use, because i can't stay with the pre-defined alerts that the platform have.

Comment: I suspect you would be better off seeing if you can configure Cayenne to send the emails for you.  Imagine what a pain it would be getting the Arduino to generate the string that contains the email and the headers.

Comment: Yes, I can send emails with Cayenne, but I want to personalize the emails.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Arduino cannot send emails directly through serial. The communication channel you have set up is a direct connection between the Arduino and Cayenne. It cannot be used for anything else other than communicating with Cayenne.

However that doesn't mean you can't try and see if there is some way of making Cayenne send emails for you. Having never used Cayenne I cannot comment on this aspect. You would be better off consulting directly with Cayenne and their users through their forums.